# Out of memory exception while loading large number of images in wp7

Tags: image, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, bitmapimage

I am loading a large number of images, say 250+ and getting this Out of memory exception.

**My Code:**

```
while (kount < imageItems.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _grid.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
    {
        BitmapImage bit=null;
        for (int j = 0; j < _grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; j++)
        {
            imgGrd = new Image();
            bit = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageItems[kount].thumb_attachment, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            imgGrd.Source = bit;

            imgGrd.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;

            _grid.Children.Add(imgGrd);
            Grid.SetRow(imgGrd, i);
            Grid.SetColumn(imgGrd, j);
            //bit = null;
            //imgGrd.Source = null;
            kount++;
         }     
     }
}
```

How to overcome this issue. thanks in advance..

Comment: Is adding memory a possibility ? If not, load less images, or smaller size image files...

Comment: How to dispose the bitmap object once the image gets the source from it..

Answer (score 1):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx for details on forcibly releasing memory used by images.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create all of your images at once. The phone has ways to create and dispose of images for you. this is done by using some of the built in ItemsControl controls. The most popular of these is the ListBox. In order to let the ListBox create and dispose of the items you'll need to create a DataTemplate that will create the image.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ImageItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding thumb_attachment}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Instead of looping through your ImageItems and creating Images manually, you allow the phone to take care of this. This requires you to create an object to bind your page to that has an `ImageItems` property.

```
public class MainViewModel // Should probably implement INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IEnumerable<ImageItem> ImageItems { get; set; }
}
```

With this your page would have it's DataContext set to be MainViewModel.

If you want to display the items in a grid then you can change the ItemsPanelTemplate of the ListBox to be the WrapPanel from the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit/).

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <toolkit:WrapPanel />
</ListBox.ItemsPanelTemplate>
```